# compare two integers using groovy in jenkins pipeline script

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-groovy

I am trying to compare two integers in jenkins script using groovy. I am getting different response each time. My doubt is how to convert the string to integer then compare it and then produce the desired output.
my script looks like this:

```
pipeline {
agent any
stages {
    stage('checkout') {
        steps {
            script{
                dec1='5.11.03'
                dec2='5.9.06'
                a=dec1.split("\\.")[1]
                b=dec2.split("\\.")[1]
                c='10'
                one="$a" as Integer
                two="$b" as Integer
                three="$c" as Integer 
                println("$one")
                println("$two")
                println("$one".compareTo(10))
                println("$two".compareTo(10))
                list1 = ("$one" >= "$three") ? 'total 7 repos' : 'total 4 repos'
                list2 = ("$two" >= "$three") ? 'total 7 repos': 'total 4 repos'
                println("the result for $dec1 is $list1")
                println("the result for $dec2 is $list2")
            }
        }
    }    
}
```

}

Here I am trying to compare the second part of a decimal digit and check if it is greater than 10. If it is greater than 10 it must print 'total 7 repos' or print 'total 4 repos'. I did also try using compareTo() which is producing different result. can anyone please help me with this. Thanks in advance.
The output i am getting is:

```
11
[Pipeline] echo
9
[Pipeline] echo
1
[Pipeline] echo
8
[Pipeline] echo
the result for 5.11.03 is total 7 repos
[Pipeline] echo
the result for 5.9.06 is total 7 repos
```

Comment: `one` is an integer, but `"$one"` is a gstring. Avoid using `"$xyz"` and your code should work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is that you are using quotes and $ symbols around your variables, but that is incorrect syntax. Groovy follows a Java-like syntax, and you can check the doc here on Groovy variables:
https://groovy-lang.org/semantics.html#_variable_assignment

Basically, your "" and $ are the problem.

Switch your lines 11-14 with:

```
println(one.compareTo(10))
println(two.compareTo(10))
list1 = (one >= three) ? 'total 7 repos' : 'total 4 repos'
list2 = (two >= three) ? 'total 7 repos': 'total 4 repos'
```

Should solve the problem.

Comment: @M B yes, changing the code as you mentioned gave the perfect output... Thank you so much for your detailed answer...